# ¿Consulta MySQL con clausulas OR y AND?

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero listar los productos que estén en dos líneas y filtrar también por la descripción, la tabla tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE productos (
    IMA_ARTICULO DOUBLE
    ,IMA_DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(100)
    ,IMA_LINEA DOUBLE
    ,IMA_IMPUESTO DOUBLE
    ,IMA_COSTO_PROMEDIO DOUBLE
    ,IMA_PRECIO1 DOUBLE
    ,IMA_PRECIO2 DOUBLE
    ,IMA_PRECIO3 DOUBLE
    ,IMA_PRECIO4 DOUBLE
    ,IMA_PRECIO5 DOUBLE
    ,IMA_PRECIO6 DOUBLE
    ,IMA_PRECIO7 DOUBLE
    ,IMA_PRECIO8 DOUBLE
    ,IMA_PRECIO9 DOUBLE
    ,IMA_PRECIO10 DOUBLE
    ,IMA_SUBLINEA DOUBLE
    ,IMA_DESCRIPCION_EXTENDIDA VARCHAR(100)
    ,IMA_DESCUENTO_MAXIMO DOUBLE
    ,POR_RENTABILIDAD_MINIMA DOUBLE
    ,EXISTENCIA DOUBLE
    ,PACK DOUBLE
    ,IMA_TIPO DOUBLE
);
```

Y la consulta la estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT *
FROM productos
WHERE IMA_LINEA = '13'
    OR IMA_LINEA = '20'
    AND IMA_DESCRIPCION LIKE '%ggg%'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que te falta es usar paréntesis para separar las expresiones:

```
select * 
from productos 
where (IMA_LINEA = '13' or IMA_LINEA = '20') and IMA_DESCRIPCION like '%ggg%'
```

Sin embargo, si quisieras buscar productos en más de dos líneas vas a tener una secuencia de ORs que se va a ir extendiendo mucho:

```
select * 
from productos 
where (IMA_LINEA = '13' or IMA_LINEA = '20' or IMA_LINEA = '30' or IMA_LINEA = '40') and IMA_DESCRIPCION like '%ggg%'
```

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es reemplazar todos esos `OR` por un `IN`:

```
select * 
from productos 
where IMA_LINEA in ('13','20','30','40') and IMA_DESCRIPCION like '%ggg%'
```

De esta forma buscas todos los productos que sean de la línea dentro del grupo `('13','20','30','40')`.

Comment: Perfecto, funciona muy bien.